# Unable to install License manager 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-license-manager, license

I uninstalled the ArcGIS 10 from my computer, the software is uninstalled , I failed to uninstall the License manager. It was giving me an error "you don't have sufficient access to uninstall ArcGIS license manager 10" while I logged in as Admin. After reading here, I downloaded REVO software, and I managed to remove it. Surprisingly when I tried to install License manager version 10.1, I got the error  "Another version of this product is already installed, Installation of this version cannot continue". Therefore I cannot install the ArcGIS 10.1.

Comment: I would double check that are Arc install files are deleted from your machine, restart and try again. If all else fails contact your ESRI rep!